# The gof function from package btergm gives AUC value of a precision-recall greater than 1

Tags: package, auc, precision-recall, goodness-of-fit

I was trying to do out-of-sample prediction using the `gof` function from package `btergm`. When calculating the **AUC** value of a **precision-recall curve** from the testing set, I get the result of  1.012909, which seems to be theoretically impossible.

How can I interpret the result, or am I doing something wrong. Thank you! Here is my code:

```
network <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/zxhqxa8h9awkzpd/network.rds?dl=1"))
model.3<- btergm(network[1:9]~edges+gwodegree(1, fixed=TRUE)+transitiveties + ctriple +
                gwidegree(1, fixed=TRUE)+mutual+gwesp(1.5, fixed=TRUE)+ttriple+
                memory(type="stability")+delrecip,R=1000)
gof.3 <-gof(model.3, nsim = 1000,target=network[[10]],formula = network[9:10]~edges+gwodegree(1,fixed=TRUE) + 
               transitiveties + ctriple +gwidegree(1,fixed=TRUE)+mutual+gwesp(1.5, fixed=TRUE)+ttriple+
               memory(type="stability")+delrecip,coef = coef(model.3), 
               statistics = rocpr)
gof.3[[1]]$auc.pr
```